# Does the phrase "sky darkening as daylight ebbs" suggest morning or evening?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase "sky darkening as daylight ebbs" seems to suggest evening to me. First, the sky's **darkening**. Also, ebb means gradually decrease (of an emotion or quality) (the best meaning I have found on the net).
However, my book says,

> Indeed, the image suggests the setting sun. This is reinforced by the
>   blowing of bugles, which may take place at sunset.

This is the analysis of the poem "The Splendour Falls" by Alfred Lord Tennyson.

> Then, it says that "sky darkening as daylight ebbs" is a correct
>   process taking place in the poem when the time is morning.

Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Your book contradicts itself -- the image does imply sunset, but that occurs at evening, not morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ebb is to grow less strong or gradually disappear. Daylight ebbs at the end of the day. Your book is wrong. The time of day in "The Splendour Falls" is sunset. Note correct spelling of 'splendour' (Tennyson was British). The quality of online or paper revision notes and study guides can be very variable, and they are no substitute for study effort.